# PDF.JS in Mobile apps Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue

Tags: javascript, cordova, sencha-touch, pdf.js

I am trying to develop an app for mobile devices using Sencha and Cordova. As PDf support is not available in the browsers of Android I decided to use PDF.JS. It is working fine while loading the local PDf files, but when tring to open remote files it is throwing an error

```
http://<remote server pdf location>. Origin file:// is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

Please let me know how to fix this issue. Is there any way to fix this in PDF.JS. I need PDF.Js files locally only as the app needs offline capability also.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

Issue is occurring when PDF.js is using WebWorkers to download the document. CORS in WebWorkers is a complete mess across browsers. (CORS is a mess IMHO anyway.)

The [usual recommendation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html) will not work:

`<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />`

Solution: do the ajax yourself, with **response type arraybuffer**, then feed response to PDF.js:

```
.success(function(buffer){
    PDFJS.getDocument(buffer);  
})
```

Answer (score 6):

Rather than calling `PDFJS.getDocument` with a URL, first get the binary data via a XMLHttpRequest, and then pass the result to the `getDocument` call in place of the URL. This will avoid the problem that seems inherent to the PDFJS library when running within a Cordova app.

The following code example is taken from the pdfJs example found here: https://bitbucket.org/butelo/pdfviewer/downloads . The issue can be resolved by making the following changes in `customview.js`

#### Replace this code:

```
/* ---- customview.js ----- */
PDFJS.getDocument(url)
    .then(function getPdfHelloWorld(_pdfDoc) {
      pdfDoc = _pdfDoc;
      renderPage(pageNum);
    });
```

#### With this code:

```
/* ---- customview.js ----- */
function callGetDocment (response) {
  // body...

  PDFJS.getDocument(response).then(function getPdfHelloWorld(_pdfDoc) {
    pdfDoc = _pdfDoc;
    renderPage(pageNum);
  });
}

function getBinaryData (url) {
    // body...
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        //binary form of ajax response,
        callGetDocment(e.currentTarget.response);
    };

    xhr.onerror = function  () {
        // body...
        alert("xhr error");
    }

    xhr.send();
}
```

#### So that you will call:

```
var url = 'http://nodetuts.com/pdf/handson-nodejs-sample.pdf';
getBinaryData(url); //call this fn on page load
```

#### Instead of:

```
var url = 'http://nodetuts.com/pdf/handson-nodejs-sample.pdf';
PDFJS.getDocument(url);
```

Comment: not working, still blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this using a simple Hack, open your pdf.js code and first beautify it using https://beautifier.io/ . Now, copy all code to a code editor and search for a string "Unable to load "
Then you will see a code something like this

[image]

Now, you have to add `i.setRequestHeader("Origin", window.location.hostname);` after
`const i = new XMLHttpRequest;` (347 LINE)

Final code will look like this

[image]
Notice a new added line at 348

Now, save it and you are ready to go!! No, Problem with CORS :)