# Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

I'm currently programming in jhispter(angularJS-spring), i have a problem, 
Implement a PDF viewer into the app.This one-> https://github.com/legalthings/angular-pdfjs-viewer

[This is my error, im trying to read a pdf of antoher domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwxpN.png)

Try using the $sce but that doesnt work

My controller function : {

```
function ViewerCustomController($scope,$sce) {
    var vm = this;
    var trustPDF = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf');
    $scope.pdf =  {
        src: trustPDF,
    }
```

}

If you know how i can configure to jhipster to CORS or give the permission Access-Control-Allow-Origin let me know plz, thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDF.JS in Mobile apps Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952810/pdf-js-in-mobile-apps-access-control-allow-origin-issue)

Answer (score 1):

The request was prevented by your browser. So you should download the resource to your server, or force the target server `www.pdf995.com` to add a response header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.